# How to pass variable in child_process and access the variable in child process in nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

Code for parent.js

```
const {spawn} = require("child_process");

const encodeImage = (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const path = req.file.path;
        let dataToSend;

        const python = spawn('python', ['controllers/script.py']);
        
        python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            dataToSend = data.toString();
        });
        python.on('close', (code) => {
            res.send(dataToSend)
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Code for child.py - Want to pass path variable as argument (for opencv function)

```py
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread(path)
```

Comment: pure javascript/python problem, not opencv. how about you simply pass that path as an argument to the subprocess... do you know what I mean? `["controllers/script.py", the_path_variable]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would probably be to pass it as a command-line argument:

In the JavaScript code:

```js
const python = spawn('python', ['controllers/script.py', path]);
```

In the Python code:

```
import sys
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread(sys.args[1])
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Worked with sys.argv[1] though.

Comment: @anadi45 that was a typo on my side, sorry about that. Edited and fixed.